# How to observe one element with mutationObserver for multiple elements in an array in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, mutation-observers

I am working on a chrome extension where I have to loop through an array of buttons to click.

Whenever a click on a connect button happens, a modal is appeared in the DOM to ask for a confirmation, and a send button needs to be clicked before moving on to the next button in the array.

The general flow is:

1. Loop through the array of buttons
2. Click the connect button
3. Wait for the modal to appear
4. Click on Send button on modal
5. Move on to the next button in the array

I am using `mutationObserver()` to wait for the modal to appear before firing off a click event on the Send button.

However, it only works once for the first element, and the loop stops.

Here's my code:

```js
async function connect(): Promise<void> {
  const connectBtn = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(
    ".connect"
  );

  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    const send = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(
      ".send"
    )[0];
    if (send.textContent === "Send") {
      send.click();
    }
  });

  for (const btn of connectBtn) {
    if (btn.textContent === "Connect") {
      btn.click();
      observer.observe(
        document.querySelector("#modal") as HTMLElement,
        {
          childList: true,
          subtree: true,
          characterData: true,
        }
      );

    }
  }

  observer.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `querySelectorAll()` if you're only using the first `.send` element? Use `querySelector()` for that.

Comment: You don't need to call `observer.observe()` in a loop. You're observing the same modal each time.

Comment: `observer.observe()` doesn't wait for the mutation to occur. The loop will click all the buttons immediately.

Comment: Yes, you were right, I had to move `observer` logic out of the loop, and it worked fine, thank you for your input!